# Can I exchange Line, True or Alipay "money" for cash somewhere in Thailand conveniently?

Tags: thailand, atms, payment, mobile-apps

Can I exchange Line, True or Alipay "money" for cash somewhere in Thailand conveniently?

So Line, True, Alipay and others are offering payment services these days. I was wondering if I had some of those "credits" or "money", is it possible to exchange it for cash somewhere in Thailand? Maybe save a few bucks on ATM fees.

Comment: These services are not available in my home country but we have similar services. Maybe you could try asking someone using those services if they can trade with you? I do it a lot in Sweden.